# greek unicode characters django and admin backend

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-admin

I have a model Teacher that has a field attribute. This attribute is filled from some predefined options.

model.py

```
#-*-coding" utf-8 -*-
field_options=[
    ('Greek letters', 'Greek letters'),
    ('Greek letters', 'Greek letters'),
    ('Greek letters', 'Greek letters'),
    ('Greek letters', 'Greek letters'),
]

class Teacher(models.Model):
    #fields here.....
    field = models.CharField(choices=field_options, max_length=20)
```

By field i mean a teacher can be a mathematician a physicst etc, but I store the greek words of these fields. When i go to the admin backend of django to store a teacher I use greek letters for the name of teacher for his last_name his address etc i choose one option for his field but when I hit save it gives me an error that the Value of the field is not a valid choice, giving me as value the unicode represantation of the field like

```
u'\u039c\u0391\u0398.... etc
```

Why does it save the other greek letters on the other fields (first name last name etc) and not the specific one? Something I can do to fix this?

EDIT:Console gives me the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2-7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:194:
UnicodeWarning:Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode -interpreting them as being unequal
    elif value == option_key
```

And one more think....I changed it after syncdb.First it was just a CharField with no choices and I added it manually (no south).Could that be the fault?

Comment: How come you're not using `unicode` literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `u` to strings in tuple:

```
(u'Greek letters', u'Greek letters'),
#('Greek letters', 'Greek letters'),
```

and check first element in tuple for `max_length=20` ...

Answer (score 2):

A general addition to unicode and its' problems:

As you use Python2.7 you sometimes run into problems with unicode. I highly recommend 
to spend 30 minutes with this subject to avoid most of the future problems. Take a look at the following talk:

**Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?**

http://pyvideo.org/video/948/